# How do I make the pickerView scroll horizontally?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I can successfully display a picker view, but I want it to scroll horizontally. I have tried the code below, but it just turns the whole entire pickerview vertically. I want the picker view to be positioned horizontally, but be able to scroll horizontally as well.

```
  func flipPicker() {
    self.subjectscroll.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.subjectscroll.transform, CGFloat(-M_PI/2))
    self.subjectscroll.reloadAllComponents()
}
```

Comment: Do you want to scroll the each of the items horizontal and also keep vertical scrolling ?

Comment: No I just want horizontal scrolling, like a selector, but I don't want the actual placement of the picker controller to be vertical so it scrolls horizontally. I want the scroll effect to be horizontal as well as the orientation.

Comment: Would you mind making a screenshot of your intention ? I may have a solution but would like to make sure that I understood you correctly.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/grIHTpe.png?1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the UI of the UIPickerView I would recommend the [iCarousel library](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). You have a lot of customizing options and can easily archive your desired effect of a horizontal selector.

Of course there are other ways to to that, for example using a UICollectionView or UIScrollView, but then you have to do more manual work.

Comment: If I wanted to do it from scratch how would I achieve the horizontal selector?

Comment: You mean the UI of the UIPickerView?

Answer (score 1):

Try also implementing `- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(nullable UIView *)view` and returning views that are rotated `M_PI/2` the opposite way.